# Less-than function in Standard ML

Tags: list, types, dictionary, sml

I'm trying to make a function in SML that takes a list and an int and returns a list of all elements that are less than the int `int * int list -> int list` I wrote the following code:

```
- fun less (e, L) = 
=   map (fn a => if a < e then a else []) L;
```

also with the following code it doesnt work also:

```
- fun less (e, L) = 
=   map (fn a => if a < e then a) L;
```

and the error im getting is :

```
stdIn:22.15-22.38 Error: types of if branches do not agree [overload]
  then branch: 'Z
  else branch: 'Y list
  in expression:
    if a < e then a else nil
```

I think the problem is with the else part but I dont know what to put in it to work, anybody have any suggestion? I should use either map, foldl, or foldr functions.

EDIT:

```
- fun less (e, L) = 
=   let
=       val acc = []
=   in
=       foldr (fn a => if a < e then a::acc else acc) acc L
=   end;
```

still gives me error, the following error :

```
stdIn:241.3-241.54 Error: operator and operand don't agree [overload]
  operator domain: 'Z * 'Y -> 'Y
  operand:         'X -> 'X list
  in expression:
    foldr (fn a => if <exp> < <exp> then <exp> :: <exp> else acc)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message is clear; since `a` has type `int` and `[]` has type `'a list`, their types are mismatched.

The problem is you chose the wrong high-order function for the task. The `filter` on List structure is best suited here:

```
fun less (e, L) = filter (fn a => a < e) L
```

You could use recursion to implement `less` explicitly, or use `foldl/foldr` to accumulate filtered lists. However, `map` seems irrelevant here.

**EDIT:**

I will give a hint about using `foldl/foldr`. You start with empty list as the accumulator. Prepend an element to the accumulator whenever that element is smaller than `e`; otherwise, return the accumulator.

**EDIT 2:**

You forgot to pass `acc` as an argument in the lambda function:

```
fun less (e, L) = foldr (fn (a, acc) => if a < e then a::acc else acc) [] L
```

And the `let..in..end` part is redundant because you use `[]` as the accumulator only.

Comment: i should use either map, foldl or foldr function

Comment: @aizen92: What I mean is using `::` constructor to make a new list `a::acc` from the element `a` and the accumulator `acc`.

Comment: yeh i figured this part but what i meant is what is prepend and is the difference with append?

Comment: @aizen92: It will change the order of elements. However, it is recommended because `::` is O(1) but `@` is O(n) by length of the left-operand list.

Comment: I've written another code but i posted in the first post for space, plz check it its giving me error

Comment: if i may ask, why didnt acc work when it was in the let scope? why cant i use it directly in the anonymous function without pass it as a param? sorry i ask to much, but I want to know why it didnt work, or what was the problem.

Comment: You always need `acc` as a param; otherwise, the function is syntactically incorrect. If there is `acc` in the let scope, it will be shadowed by the new `acc` param. So the let scope here is not related to the error; it is only superfluous.

Comment: `map` may not be completely irrelevant. It is possible to write `filter` in terms of `map` and `concat`. But I agree for this case it is simplest to just use `filter`